# ffmpeg merge audio, video and subtitle does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have seen numerous guides but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. This is the ffprobe code:

```
ffprobe version N-104437-ge84c83ef98-20211028 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10-win32 (GCC) 20210408
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20211028
  libavutil      57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavcodec     59. 12.100 / 59. 12.100
  libavformat    59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 15.100 /  8. 15.100
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'filesource.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.5 + libmatroska v1.4.8
    creation_time   : 2019-06-28T17:22:18.000000Z
  Duration: 00:24:00.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3203 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 3071385
      DURATION-eng    : 00:23:59.982000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 34525
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 552842428
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v22.0.0 ('At The End Of The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-28 17:22:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 128000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:00.078000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 62019
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 23041253
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v22.0.0 ('At The End Of The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-28 17:22:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 102
      DURATION-eng    : 00:21:00.020000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 243
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 16208
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v22.0.0 ('At The End Of The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-28 17:22:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:3(ita): Subtitle: ass (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      title           : Sottotitoli completi
      BPS-eng         : 107
      DURATION-eng    : 00:21:00.020000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 257
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 16881
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v22.0.0 ('At The End Of The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-28 17:22:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:4(spa): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 121
      DURATION-eng    : 00:23:34.740000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 322
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 21506
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v22.0.0 ('At The End Of The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-28 17:22:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:5(por): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 143
      DURATION-eng    : 00:23:39.750000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 318
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 25453
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v22.0.0 ('At The End Of The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-28 17:22:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:6: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 6
```

looking for various solutions here on stackoverflow I found this command that should work:

```
ffmpeg -progress pipe:1 -hide_banner -i "pathsource.mkv" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:3 -c:a aac -c:v copy -c:s mov_text "destination.mp4"
```

Or

```
ffmpeg -progress pipe:1 -hide_banner -i "pathsource.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:a aac -c:v copy -c:s mov_text "destination.mp4"
```

The problem is that when I run it it does its operations but the final result is video + audio without subtitles. As if he didn't see them. Can anyone give me some advice on how to do it? Thank you
I want Video #0:0, audio #0:1 and subtitles #0:3. Can i do it? Thanks

EDIT:

ffprobe of the final results (subtitle doesn't exist). Why?

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '483.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.8.100
  Duration: 00:24:00.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2672 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2536 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](jpn): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

ffprobe of the same file if i use the new version of ffmpeg

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '481.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.17.100
  Duration: 00:24:00.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3203 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3065 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](jpn): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](ita): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

however, even if they appear, you will not see the subtitles on the screen.

Comment: **1.** What do you mean "without subtitles"? Could it be the video player configurations? Try using VLC media player, and enable the subtitles (Subtitles -> Sub track -> Track 1). **2.** In case it's not the player configuration, please post the FFprobe output for `destination.mp4`. **3.** Try updating FFmpeg version, it's looks like you are using a "Nightly build" version.

Comment: 1) I mean that the final result of ffmpeg is audio + video without the subtitles imprinted even if I chose them in the command entered. 2) i have updated the main post 3) I tried with the latest version available and nothing has changed in the result :) I will also post that result in the post edit because this time the subtitles appear but they are not displayed on the screen. How come?

Comment: In case the subtitle stream exists in `destination.mp4`, the issue is probably the configuration of the Payer. Have you tried VLC Player? Can you see the subtitles when playing `pathsource.mkv` (make sure you don't have an external SRT or SUB file)? Would you like to use "burned subtitles" instead? (making the subtitles part of the video makes it shown regardless of the player configuration).

Comment: the subtitles seem to appear in ffprobe but if I open vlc it doesn't let me choose them. Instead, in the mkv file you and I see them (the source one). So my problem is "how to put subtitles in the video and show them" burned ".
Basically I would like to read the subtitles of the video by simply opening the video with any player without having to set anything on vlc. It's possible? If so, how? Because I've been trying them all for days, I can create an mp4 with audio and video that I would like by deleting the others but the subtitles just don't want to be imprinted on the video.

Comment: Can you help me pls?

Comment: I don't have time right now. Google search `ffmpeg burn subtitles`. Keep in mind that "burning" the subtitles requires video re-encoding and looses some video quality (add `-crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv444` for keeping quality, but getting larger file size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can burn text subtitles (hardsubs) using [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1).

The advantage of using "burned" subtitles is that the subtitles are going to be displayed regardless of the video player configuration.

The main disadvantage is that we have to re-encode the video.
Re-encoding looses quality, and may result larger file size (larger file for keeping the quality closer to the original quality).

For burning the second subtitles steam (Italian) in your case, you may use `pathsource.mkv:si=1`.
Since the Italian stream is the default, we don't have to add `:si=1`.

---

Command line (example) for adding "burned" subtitles:

```
ffmpeg -y -i pathsource.mkv -vf "subtitles=pathsource.mkv:force_style='Fontsize=72,Fontname=Arial Bold,PrimaryColour=&HFFFFFF&'" -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv444p destination.mp4
```

---

- `-crf 17` is used for high quality, with the cost of larger file size (set higher value for lower quality).
- `-yuv444` is used for better quality (better subtitles quality with the cost of larger file size), but it's not critical.
- You may play with the font style (size, font, color...).

---

In case you still want to try the embedded subtitles stream (without re-encoding), you may try setting the stream as "default" and "forced":

```
ffmpeg -y -progress pipe:1 -hide_banner -i "pathsource.mkv" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:3 -c:a aac -c:v copy -c:s mov_text -disposition:s default+forced "destination.mp4"
```

Note: It looks like the "forced" option is not working in this case.

---

### Testing:

Build synthetic video with audio and two subtitles streams:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -sub_charenc CP1252 -i in0.srt -sub_charenc CP1252 -i in1.srt -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map:v 0 -map:a "[a]" -map:s 3 -map:s 4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 22050 -scodec ass -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ita -disposition:s:s:1 default+forced -t 10 pathsource.mkv
```

Sample content of `in0.srt`:

```
1
00:00:00,0 --> 00:00:01,0
Eng 0 to 1

2
00:00:01,0 --> 00:00:02,0
Eng 1 to 2

3
00:00:02,0 --> 00:00:03,0
Eng 2 to 3

4
00:00:03,0 --> 00:00:04,0
Eng 3 to 4

5
00:00:04,0 --> 00:00:05,0
Eng 4 to 5
```

Content of `in1.srt`:

```
1
00:00:00,0 --> 00:00:01,0
Ita 0 to 1

2
00:00:01,0 --> 00:00:02,0
Ita 1 to 2

3
00:00:02,0 --> 00:00:03,0
Ita 2 to 3

4
00:00:03,0 --> 00:00:04,0
Ita 3 to 4

5
00:00:04,0 --> 00:00:05,0
Ita 4 to 5
```

Sample result after executing `ffmpeg -y -i pathsource.mkv -vf "subtitles=pathsource.mkv:force_style='Fontsize=72,Fontname=Arial Bold,PrimaryColour=&HFFFFFF&'" -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv444p destination.mp4`:

[image]

---

For the embedded subtitles stream you may have to modify the video player settings.

VLC Player example:

[image]